# perl script for reading data with in angular brackets < and > not working

Tags: regex, perl

My task is to read data within angule brackets and write to another file. I have developed a script but it is not working. If there are any modifications required then please correct me.

The sample data which I want to read is like this

```
Textbooks written by author1 `{ <sam>,<january>,<2015>},{<rga>,<feb>,<2005>},`
```

This is my Perl program

```
#!usr/bin/local/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
my @c_result; 
my @c_result_array;
my %hash;
my $file = 'c_template.c';
open CFILE, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";
my @content;
my $fileoutput="output_c.c";
open OUTFILE,"> $fileoutput" or die $!;
my $i;
while(<CFILE>)
{
for $i  (@content)
    {
        $_ = $i;
        if(/<[\w*_*]+>/)
        {
            @c_result = /<[\w*_*]+>/g;
            for my $i (@c_result)
            { 
                my $key=substr($i,1,length($i)-2);
                $i=$key;
                push @c_result_array,$i;
                print OUTFILE $i ."=>@c_result_array";
                print OUTFILE "\n";
            }
        }   
    }   
}
close OUTFILE;
close CFILE;
```

Comment: Sample data { <SAM_NO_1>, <MONTH_NO_1>, <UNIT_1> }

Comment: no it is not standard format  ; my sample data is like above

Comment: can you tell me what is mean by standard format .

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: i will give an example that assume we have one paragraph in between that paragraph we have data like { <SAM_NO_1>, <MONTH_NO_1>, <UNIT_1> }. so my goal is to bring SAM_NO_1 out and print it in a file .

Comment: the output as per the sample data is SAM_NO_1 ,MONTH_NO_1 ,   like

Comment: as per requirement i cant do my data in standard format ...

Comment: Please add a real multi-line sample of `c_template.c` to your question and describe the corresponding output that you would like

Comment: Take a look at [Text::Balanced](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Balanced).

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you never populate `@content` but you attempt to iterate it.

In your regular expressions: `[]` are used to define *[character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharclass.html)*, `()` are used to define *[capture groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)*.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very unclear and imprecise, but from your code I think this is what you want

```
#!/usr/bin/local/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my ($file, $fileoutput) = qw/ c_template.c output_c.c /;

open my $c_fh,   '<',  $file or die qq{Could not open "$file" for input: $!};
open my $out_fh, '>',  $fileoutput or die qq{Could not open "$fileoutput" for output: $!};
select $out_fh;

while ( <$c_fh> ) {
  next unless my @fields = /<([^<>]+)>/g;
  chomp;
  print "$_ => @fields\n";
}

close $out_fh or die qq{Could not close "$fileoutput": $!};
```

**output**

```
Textbooks written by author1 `{ <sam>,<january>,<2015>},{<rga>,<feb>,<2005>},` => sam january 2015 rga feb 2005
```